# Half Sine Pulse Shaping - Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, telecommunication, modulation, software-defined-radio

The standard of 802.15.4 specfies the following:

> The chip sequences representing each data symbol are modulated onto
>   the carrier using O-QPSK with halfsine pulse shaping.

For pulse shaping the following is mentioned:

> The half-sine pulse shape used to represent each baseband chip is described by

```
p(t) = sin(pi*(t/(2*Tc))) , 0 < t < 2Tc where Tc = Chip Rate (2 MChips/s) 
     = 0, otherwise
```

I am using the `modem.oqpskmod` function for modulation and am not sure if this has a half sine pulse shaping built in.

Could someone guide me how should this be implemented in Matlab as I have not found a function in Matlab for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your function but to get that shape you can just say

```
p = sin(pi*(t/(2*Tc))) .* (0 < t & t < 2*Tc);
```